# How to block github https clone access of your Repository

Tags: github, repository

How to block github https clone access to my repository so that whenever any user try to clone my repo over https get error .They can only clone my repo using SSH Keys.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.  GitHub doesn't distinguish between HTTPS clones and SSH clones in this way.  Some features, such as deploy keys, are only usable over SSH, and some features, such as GitHub Apps (and hence most CI infrastructure) tend to be accessible only over HTTPS.

If there's a specific goal you're trying to achieve, you should ask how to accomplish that instead.  For example, if you're trying to prevent users in your organization from using a weak password to clone, you could require them to enable 2FA before joining the organization, which will let them clone only using an SSH key or a randomly generated token.